# Is there an explanation why python keeps on saying an error that "Can't convert 'Answers' object to str implicitly?"

Tags: python

I am building a vocab quiz to practice python. However, Python keeps on telling me that they can only link str, not "Answers", to strs. Below is the code:

```
class Answers:                                       
    def __init__(self, synonym, nsynonyms1, nsynonyms2, nsynonyms3):
        self.synonym = synonym
        self.nsynonyms1 = nsynonyms1
        self.nsynonyms2 = nsynonyms2
        self.nsynonyms3 = nsynonyms3


words = ['austere', 'desecrate', 'excaberate', 'delineate', 'indite', 'adumbrate', 'pivotal', 'zephyr', 'tempest', 'accost', 'contrite', 'contravene']

#Words in possible list each line up with words in words
possible = ['harsh', 'violate', 'worsen', 'describe', 'compose', 'report', 'crucial', 'wind', 'gale', 'confront', 'penitant', 'infringe']

words[0] = Answers(possible[0], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3]) # 'austere'
words[1] = Answers(possible[1], possible[2], possible[3], possible[4]) # 'desecrate' 
words[2] = Answers(possible[2], possible[3], possible[4], possible[5]) # 'excaberate'
words[3] = Answers(possible[3], possible[4], possible[5], possible[6]) # 'delineate'
words[4] = Answers(possible[4], possible[5], possible[6], possible[7]) # 'indite'
words[5] = Answers(possible[5], possible[6], possible[7], possible[8]) # 'adumbrate'
words[6] = Answers(possible[6], possible[7], possible[8], possible[9]) # 'pivotal'
words[7] = Answers(possible[7], possible[8], possible[9], possible[10]) # 'zephyr'
words[8] = Answers(possible[8], possible[9], possible[10], possible[11]) # 'tempest'
words[9] = Answers(possible[9], possible[10], possible[11], possible[1]) # 'accost' *One of the nsynonyms goes back instead of forward
words[10] = Answers(possible[10], possible[11], possible[1], possible[2]) # 'contrite' *Two of the nsynonyms goes back instead of forward
words[11] = Answers(possible[11], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3]) # 'contravene' *3 of the nsynonyms goes back instead of forward


def question_test():
    corr_questions = 0
    for word in words:
        choice = input("What is a synonym for the word, '" + word + "'? \n (a) " + word.synonym +  "\n (b) " + word.nsynonyms1 + "\n (c) " + word.nsynonyms2 + " \n (d) " + word.nsynonyms3)

question_test()
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 33, in <module>
    question_test()
  File "demo.py", line 31, in question_test
    choice = input("What is a synonym for the word, '" + word + "'? \n (a) " + word.synonym +  "\n (b) " + word.nsynonyms1 + "\n (c) " + word.nsynonyms2 + " \n (d) " + word.nsynonyms3)
TypeError: must be str, not Answers
```

Comment: You might be interested in using a [dictionary](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) to create a mapping of answers to their possible choices.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop:

```
for word in words:
    choice = input("What is a synonym for the word, '" + word + "'? \n (a) " + word.synonym +  "\n (b) " + word.nsynonyms1 + "\n (c) " + word.nsynonyms2 + " \n (d) " + word.nsynonyms3)
```

The variable `word` needs to be a string for this to work. But note your `words` list has elements which are of type Answer:

```
words[0] = Answers(possible[0], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3]) # 'austere'
```

Instead you should be using some attribute of the `Answers` class in your loop.

That being said, a better approach would be to refactor your code. Note that you're defining `words` as a list of strings, and then you're overwriting it:

```
words = ['austere', 'desecrate', 'excaberate', 'delineate', 'indite', 'adumbrate', 'pivotal', 'zephyr', 'tempest', 'accost', 'contrite', 'contravene']
...
words[0] = Answers(possible[0], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3]) # 'austere'
words[1] = Answers(possible[1], possible[2], possible[3], possible[4]) # 'desecrate' 
...
```

Maybe you meant to use different lists?

Answer (score 1):

`words[x]` is not a string as you expect, you replaced it with answer object.

```
words[0] = Answers(possible[0], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3]) # 'austere'
```

Answer (score 1):

convert Answers object into str object

first, implement `__str__` method for Answers object

then, before `+` to another str, use `str(word)`

```py
class Answers:                                       
    def __init__(self, word, synonym, nsynonyms1, nsynonyms2, nsynonyms3):
        self.word = word
        self.synonym = synonym
        self.nsynonyms1 = nsynonyms1
        self.nsynonyms2 = nsynonyms2
        self.nsynonyms3 = nsynonyms3

    def __str__(self):
        return F"Answers({self.word})"

words = ['austere', 'desecrate', 'excaberate', 'delineate', 'indite', 'adumbrate', 'pivotal', 'zephyr', 'tempest', 'accost', 'contrite', 'contravene']

#Words in possible list each line up with words in words
possible = ['harsh', 'violate', 'worsen', 'describe', 'compose', 'report', 'crucial', 'wind', 'gale', 'confront', 'penitant', 'infringe']

words[0] = Answers(words[0], possible[0], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3]) # 'austere'
words[1] = Answers(words[1], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3], possible[4]) # 'desecrate' 
words[2] = Answers(words[2], possible[2], possible[3], possible[4], possible[5]) # 'excaberate'
words[3] = Answers(words[3], possible[3], possible[4], possible[5], possible[6]) # 'delineate'
words[4] = Answers(words[4], possible[4], possible[5], possible[6], possible[7]) # 'indite'
words[5] = Answers(words[5], possible[5], possible[6], possible[7], possible[8]) # 'adumbrate'
words[6] = Answers(words[6], possible[6], possible[7], possible[8], possible[9]) # 'pivotal'
words[7] = Answers(words[7], possible[7], possible[8], possible[9], possible[10]) # 'zephyr'
words[8] = Answers(words[8], possible[8], possible[9], possible[10], possible[11]) # 'tempest'
words[9] = Answers(words[9], possible[9], possible[10], possible[11], possible[1]) # 'accost' *One of the nsynonyms goes back instead of forward
words[10] = Answers(words[10], possible[10], possible[11], possible[1], possible[2]) # 'contrite' *Two of the nsynonyms goes back instead of forward
words[11] = Answers(words[11], possible[11], possible[1], possible[2], possible[3]) # 'contravene' *3 of the nsynonyms goes back instead of forward


def question_test():
    corr_questions = 0
    for word in words:
        choice = input("What is a synonym for the word, '" + str(word) + "'? \n (a) " + word.synonym +  "\n (b) " + word.nsynonyms1 + "\n (c) " + word.nsynonyms2 + " \n (d) " + word.nsynonyms3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`word` is an `Answers` object, not the string that was originally in the `words` list.

You can copy the original word to an `Answers` attribute, so you can extract it when printing the question.

```
class Answers:                                       
    def __init__(self, word, synonym, nsynonyms1, nsynonyms2, nsynonyms3):
        self.word = word
        self.synonym = synonym
        self.nsynonyms1 = nsynonyms1
        self.nsynonyms2 = nsynonyms2
        self.nsynonyms3 = nsynonyms3

words = ['austere', 'desecrate', 'excaberate', 'delineate', 'indite', 'adumbrate', 'pivotal', 'zephyr', 'tempest', 'accost', 'contrite', 'contravene']

#Words in possible list each line up with words in words
possible = ['harsh', 'violate', 'worsen', 'describe', 'compose', 'report', 'crucial', 'wind', 'gale', 'confront', 'penitant', 'infringe']

l = len(possible)
questions = [Answers(word, possible[i % l], possible[(i + 1) % l], possible[(i + 2) % l], possible[(i + 3) % l]) for i, word in enumerate(words)]

def question_test():
    corr_questions = 0
    for word in questions:
        choice = input("What is a synonym for the word, '" + word.word + "'? \n (a) " + word.synonym +  "\n (b) " + word.nsynonyms1 + "\n (c) " + word.nsynonyms2 + " \n (d) " + word.nsynonyms3)

question_test()
```